# Google tag manager ecommerace analytics in react native

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I am developing an e-commerce application using react native. We are planning to integrate the e-commerce analytics tracking.

What is the best method to integrate google tag manager to log advance e-commerce events?

Or is there any method to log the e-commerce events to Google analytics in react native?

Currently I am using firebase to log the events. But it does not support detail e-commerce reports in the console.